# How to detect empty fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string

I have a column (nvarchar) which has some nonsense data and I'm trying to make a clean up. What I want to do is to delete all blank fields and have only fields with texts or numbers. What I tried so far:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE col='' OR col=' ' OR LEN(col)=0 OR LTRIM(RTRIM(col))=''
```

However, there are still some blank fields. Some of them are like these (single quotes and commas are not included, I write them to show where they start and end)

'     ' , '               ', '

', '

'

Comment: I already wrote it, nvarchar

Comment: what is the "good" data like in that column? I have a function that basically removes all spaces and strange chararcters from a string which could help youbut depends on the data that you want to keep

Comment: Have you tried IsNull for blank fields ??

Comment: I want to leave fields with visible text; not space or new line. @suraj yes I tried that too but sometimes different entries come like enter space space enter enter space.... goes on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do exactly the same:

```
DELETE 
FROM myTable 
WHERE col=''
```

If you still have rows, it is because you have other characters that does not appear like linefeed

This will delete all rows that doesn't have alphanumeric characters in the text

```
DELETE 
FROM myTable 
WHERE col not like '%[0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

You can add more characters. Example:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z,'']
```

<--- added quote and comma to rows that shouldn't be deleted

Answer (score 1):

you can replace the extra signs with blank and then trim from left and right if they are = '' then delete 
like this :

```
DELETE FROM myTable 
WHERE LEN(col)=0 
        OR 
       LTRIM(
        RTRIM(
                REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,'.',''),'''',''),'"',''),',','')
            )
        )=''
```

Comment: and you can drop ltrim and rtrim with the same result